# Svelte seeing a confusing error with rollup

Tags: typescript, svelte, rollup

Hello I am using rollup builder and trying to implement typescript with my application at the moment I am receiving a very general error `index.mjs:266 Uncaught ReferenceError: core is not defined`. This is not pointing me in any direction. I have double check my rollup and tsconfig and haven't made any progress. Can anybody help me?

Here is my code so far

`rollup.config.js`

```
import svelte from 'rollup-plugin-svelte';
import commonjs from '@rollup/plugin-commonjs';
import resolve from '@rollup/plugin-node-resolve';
import livereload from 'rollup-plugin-livereload';
import { terser } from 'rollup-plugin-terser';
import typescript from '@rollup/plugin-typescript';
import css from 'rollup-plugin-css-only';
import sveltePreprocess from 'svelte-preprocess';

const production = !process.env.ROLLUP_WATCH;

function serve() {
    let server;

    function toExit() {
        if (server) server.kill(0);
    }

    return {
        writeBundle() {
            if (server) return;
            server = require('child_process').spawn('npm', ['run', 'start', '--', '--dev'], {
                stdio: ['ignore', 'inherit', 'inherit'],
                shell: true,
            });

            process.on('SIGTERM', toExit);
            process.on('exit', toExit);
        },
    };
}

export default {
    input: 'src/main.js',
    output: {
        sourcemap: true,
        format: 'iife',
        name: 'app',
        file: 'public/build/bundle.js',
    },
    plugins: [
        svelte({
            compilerOptions: {
                // enable run-time checks when not in production
                dev: !production,
            },
            preprocess: sveltePreprocess({
                sourceMap: !production,
                postcss: {
                    plugins: [require('tailwindcss'), require('autoprefixer')],
                },
            }),
            extensions: ['.html', '.svelte', '.ts'],
        }),
        // we'll extract any component CSS out into
        // a separate file - better for performance
        css({ output: 'bundle.css' }),

        // If you have external dependencies installed from
        // npm, you'll most likely need these plugins. In
        // some cases you'll need additional configuration -
        // consult the documentation for details:
        // https://github.com/rollup/plugins/tree/master/packages/commonjs
        resolve({
            browser: true,
            dedupe: ['svelte'],
        }),
        commonjs({
            include: 'node_modules/**'
        }),
        typescript({
            sourceMap: !production,
            rootDir: "./src",
         }),

        // In dev mode, call `npm run start` once
        // the bundle has been generated
        !production && serve(),

        // Watch the `public` directory and refresh the
        // browser on changes when not in production
        !production && livereload('public'),

        // If we're building for production (npm run build
        // instead of npm run dev), minify
        production && terser(),
    ],
    watch: {
        clearScreen: false,
    },
};
```

`tsconfig.json`

```
  "extends": "@tsconfig/svelte/tsconfig.json",

  "include": ["src/**/*", "/node_modules"],
  "exclude": ["node_modules/*", "public/*"],
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es2017",
    "importsNotUsedAsValues": "error",
    "isolatedModules": true,
    "sourceMap": true,
    "strict": false,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true
  }
}
```

Comment: @raina77ow Does this help?

Comment: @raina77ow seems like it doesn't want to work in Brave browser for me works in other browsers :)

Comment: Check [this issue](https://github.com/sveltejs/svelte/issues/3699), it might be similar. In general, if there's an issue try to provide the [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), because the info you've provided so far is not really helpful.